# "2D" plot with square colour in grid indicative of value - the ArcGIS look

Tags: matlab, plot

I've looked up surface plots and contour plots but cannot find the appropriate format. I am not concerned with height and want a bird's eye view of a flat grid - much like the format of ARCGis.

I have random values between 0 to 10 in a 7x7 matrix.

I want to draw a grid 7 by 7 that is 2D where the individual grid cells are block-coloured according to their value.

The top left value of the matrix is the top left cell of the plot and so on. They should align.

I don't want to have to export matlab's output and put it back into ARCG each time I get a result. Thanks for your advice guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 2D array, you should be able to just "show" it like an image. Try using `imagesc()` with `colormap on`. You can change the colormap, size, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I will try implement this!

Comment: Is imagesc capable of plotting multiple images? If I have 7x7 over 5 years, telling matlab to plot imagesc 5 times only plots one. Like this: imagesc(result(:,:,1))..imagesc(result(:,:,2))..etc.

Comment: You need to use `figure` or `subplot`. Otherwise it will put the images into the active/current axes, erasing whatever was there before.